# How can I overload the << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have to create a Matrix class, and I got some problem to overload the operators

I would like to fill up a matrices using the `<<` operator

```
Matrix<double> u3(2,2);

u3 << 3.3, 4, 3, 6;


template<class T>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::operator <<(T in){
    //Fill up the matrix, m[0] = 3.3, m[1]=4...
    return *this;
}
```

How overload this operator?

Comment: And in this case, you have two operators to overload: `<<` and `,`.

Comment: why do you print it out in your operator then?

Comment: have a look at va_start, va_arg, and va_end too!

Comment: Are you okay with using the recent `c++11`? If so, consider using `std::initializer_list` instead.

Comment: I would like to use in an Arm processor

Comment: You should probably write a more complete example... It's quite unclear what you actually want to achieve... Like, what size matrix? Fill up how? Please improve the question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an approach using commas:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Matrix {

    struct Adder {
        Matrix& m;
        int index;

        Adder(Matrix& m) : m(m), index(1) {}

        Adder& operator,(float value) {
            m.set(index++, value);
            return *this;
        }    
    };

    void set(int index, float value) {
        // Assign value to position `index` here.
        // I'm just printing stuff to show you what would happen...
        cout << "Matrix[" << index << "] = " << value << endl;
    }

    Adder operator<<(float value) {
        set(0, value);
        return Adder(*this);
    }

};
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/W75LaH

Some explanations:

The syntax `matrix << 5, 10, 15, 20` is achieved in two steps:

- `matrix << 5` is evaluated first; it sets the first element to 5 and returns a temporary `Adder` object that handles further insertions (remembering the index for the next insert)
- `Adder` has overloaded `operator,` that performs the following inserts after each comma.

Comment: I assume you know how to turn this into a template and handle more dimensions. Please leave a comment if you need further help and I'll expand.

Comment: Thank for the idea. I have one more question, I overload the `Matrix*scalar`, but how can I overload `scalar*Matrix` operation?

Comment: Easily; Make the overloaded operator a regular 2-argument function, not a 1-argument member function.

Answer (score 1):

An approach like this would work:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
class Mat {
public:
  T val; 
};

template <typename T>
Mat<T>& operator<<(Mat<T>& v, T in) {
  std::cout << in << " ";
  return v;
}

int main() {
  Mat<int> m;
  m << 1 << 2 << 3;
}
```

Note that I am using a free `operator<<` function, and do not use commas between the values.

Comment: This approach could work too but it would require `Mat` to have an extra counter variable to remember the index between insertions. And you'd need something like another `operator<<` overload with a special token to be able to reset this index between several different assignment sequences. 0 for now, will change to +1 if you make it complete :-)

Comment: @Kos you could accomplish this by filling up the matrix with nan's and filling in one nan pr operator<< (not optimal I know, but simple). I didn't read the question that he wanted us to fill in the intrinsics, he just wanted to get the overloading correct.